# Is this a viable map-making method in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dictionary

This is a code sample taken from the Google Maps API developer's guide. I'm not super experienced with JavaScript, but I have never seen this syntax before. The portion which confuses me is the first part, where they say "var citymap={};" and then seemingly go on to declare a bunch of citymap keys. Then, later, they say " for (var city in citymap) {" etc.

Is this the only/the proper method for making a map in JavaScript?

```
// Create an object containing LatLng, population.
var citymap = {};
citymap['chicago'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.878113, -87.629798),
  population: 2842518
};
citymap['newyork'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.714352, -74.005973),
  population: 8143197
};
citymap['losangeles'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.052234, -118.243684),
  population: 3844829
}
var cityCircle;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.09024, -95.712891),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
      mapOptions);

  for (var city in citymap) {
    // Construct the circle for each value in citymap. We scale population by 20.
    var populationOptions = {
      strokeColor: "#FF0000",
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: "#FF0000",
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      map: map,
      center: citymap[city].center,
      radius: citymap[city].population / 20
    };
    cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try to explain each bit of code ...

```
var citymap = {};
```

This creates an empty object ... the following adds values to the object :

```
citymap['chicago'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.878113, -87.629798),
  population: 2842518
};
```

This adds a new key ('chicago') and adds some properties to it (`center` and `population`) the final but which loops the object is

```
for (var city in citymap) {
```

this statement loops the `citymap` object, assigning `city` to the key of each object. To access the properties the code uses

```
citymap[city].center
citymap[city].population
```

Its the best way to create and loop and object with multiple values. There is some [really good documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) on working with Objects in JavaScript

Comment: Well-explained. It was as I suspected. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
var citymap = {}
```

means , they are creating an object with name citymap.

Its a shorthand for `var citymap = new Object();`

http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/

Comment: @Aerovistae 

Mark answer , if it helped you.

Comment: You can't mark an accepted answer for like 8 minutes after asking a question, or something like that. FYI.

Answer (score 0):

Expression citymap['losangeles'] is the same as citymap.longeles. You must be carefull, if you delete from hash map, because you can write delete citymap['losangeles'], but you cannot write delete citymap.longeles. Expression citymap['losangeles'] is also useable, when you have a key in String variable:

```
 var city = 'losangeles';
 var x = citymap[city]; //good
 var x = citymap.city; //error
```